# Problems with new added bones

Tags: mesh, bones, rigify

I'm kind of new to bone rigging and I'm having some issues with it. After I added a Meta-Rig (from the Rigify Add-On) and aligned all the bones with the character I made, I decided to add some new bones near the butt part of my character to try prevent some deformation when the character's leg move.

[image: 1]

The problem I'm having is that these two new bones (they are called pelvisL_1 and pelvisR_1), even if they are part of the Meta-Rig and parented to the main "spine" bone, don't move any mesh. I tried to go to weight painting thinking that these bones didn't have any mesh to move but Blender doesn't seem to "see" them instead.

[image: 2]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The new bones probably don't have any vertex groups to control, but you can select the armature, shift select the character *Object*, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select one of these bones with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click, shift left click to select the other bones, and in the *Weights* panel, click on *Assign Automatic from Bones*, which will create the new vertex groups and assign the vertices to these groups:

[image]

Comment: wow it works! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from moonboots is probably correct I'll just try and clear it up a little and provide a different solution.

If your mesh was parented to your rig before you created the new bones then Blender will not have created vertex groups for those bones (as they didn't exist when the groups were created).

Another solution is to just go to the vertex groups panel and create new vertex groups manually and give them the same names as the new bones.